# why external tables do not work in netezza?

Tags: netezza

I am working with the Netezza Emulator on Server A.  I am having issues running queries on external tables.

i have a text file named test.txt on Server B.  I have the Netezza odbc connector with the following version paramters:

```
    Driver version          : 'Release 7.2.0.0 [Build 40845]'
    NPS version             : '07.02.0001 Release 7.2.1.0 [Build 46322]'
    Database                : <sanitized>
```

when I attempt to run this query on server B:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE testtable (   COL1 INTEGER ) USING (  DATAOBJECT('/var/tmp/test.txt')     DELIMITER 30    NULLVALUE 'N'   ESCAPECHAR '\'  TIMESTYLE '24HOUR'  BOOLSTYLE 'T_F'     CTRLCHARS TRUE  LOGDIR '/data/data/HAGDEMO/temp/'   Y2BASE 2000     ENCODING 'INTERNAL'     REMOTESOURCE 'ODBC' );
```

the response is there every time.
However, if I perform the query:

```
SELECT * FROM testtable;
```

It works 50% of the time.  The first 50% is normal.  The other 50% results in a hang.  No error, no response, not even a return cursor.  Just a hang.

while tracking the pg.log file, I see no errors. or anything that would show a problem.  It acknowledges the query and continues on it's day as if it's time for a beer.

Is there anything I should be working?  This is with the initial admin login, so I know all permissions are there.

What am I missing?
Thanks

UPDATE #1:
When running the queries, the query does appear in the session manager as normal, then hangs.  When I upgrade the query to critical status, it executes immediately.  What is the reason for this?  I don't want to have to manually update priorities over odbc every time.  Thanks.

Comment: Your query may be affected by workload management/GRA limits.  When your query appears to be hanging, check the state in nzadmin->active queries, or select * from _v_qrystat - and look for state_text.  Is it pending, running, or queued?

Comment: Thanks Scott.  They say "running"

Comment: One other question.  what tool and os are you running the query from? I understand you've installed the netezza client code and are using odbc in some form, but more specifically are you using some command line interface or other tool?

Comment: I'm running the query from datastage via odbc on linux.  I am using netezza administrator to watch over the sessions.  In addition, this issue resolves mostly when I'm running queries for External tables.

Comment: You mention having access to the pg.log, so can you also try running "nzsqa schedqueues -sys" when you have one of your queries that's hanging?  Run it a couple of times and look for you planid and see if it's in a RUNNING section, and look at the values for  age:snip/plan/nullio  to see if any of those three values are increasing over the time it's hung.

Comment: Thanks.  yes it's climbing as the job continues

Comment: You say that the first 50% of the time the query works normally. How much (absolute number) is that 50%? This pattern, working for the first queries - failing for the rest, feels like a resource being exhausted and/or not being freed. Furthermore, how is your user authentication set up? I am not familiar with Netezza and I am shooting in the dark, but you could also see if there is something in https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.reln.doc/c_relnotes_known_issues.html that hits home.

Comment: I performed multiple tests to find out the status of the server while the query is in action, and I can't find where the resources are being exhausted.  Even the VM Administrator is saying we are hitting only 10% of the server's resources.  It just hangs.  No reports, no red-lines, nothing.  Just a dead stall.

Comment: When I said resources, I was mostly thinking about connections from a connection pool that are not freed for reuse. Shooting in the dark, I believe. So, how many queries succeed in the beginning, before they start to hang?

Comment: it looks like 12 queries go in.  The last six are the External table queries.  It hangs on a one of the queries, thus making the others stick.

Comment: Did you look at the known issues (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.reln.doc/c_relnotes_known_issues.html), especially the ones that mention `external` and simultaneous operations on external tables?

Comment: I think you are doing everything OK, and external tables with DataStage is a time-honored method/tool to use.  This sounds to me as if it might be a timing issue driven by the ODBC driver.  Or, since you have 7.2.1 you probably have LBS enabled.  So one last guess.  Check the output of "nzsystem showRegistry | grep host.schedMediumQueryLimitSecs" and "host.schedFlags=2"

Comment: first one says host.schedMediumQueryLimitSecs     = 60
the second one has no response.  Thank you so much

Comment: If you have the ability to pause the system, you can try disabling LBS like this:  "nzsystem pause" followed by "nzsystem set -arg host.schedMediumQueryLimitSecs=0" followed by "nzsystem resume" and then try a couple of iterations of your datastage job.  This is something of a longshot, but it can't hurt to try it.  You can revert by repeating the process and reverting back to host.schedMediumQueryLimitSecs=60 . This is probably something better fielded by support, but we can try!           

Are you sure you want to change the system configuration (y]n)? °né y    

nzsystem resume

Comment: Thanks Scott.  Still no dice.  Still holding and no change.  What else you got?  I'm going to give you the 500 points for the effort.  Thanks much.

Comment: well, I wanted to.

Comment: ok.  jobs still stick. it looks like it just hangs there.  I even downgraded the driver with the hope that it'll work.

Comment: Does the DATAOBJECT path value refer to a directory on the host or the DataStage server or somewhere else? If it's on the DataStage server you will need to use the RemoteSource ODBC external table option. Also, how was the file created? Does it contain any control characters for example? When you say 'hang' do you mean it ends with an error (check .log/.bad files) or just never ends at all?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that by default External Tables are expected to be visible from the Host (Server A).

Unless */var/tmp/test.txt* is visible from the Host, it won't work without specifying the **RemoteSource ODBC** option, and even then, the client submitting the select SQL must also be running on Server B (i.e. it has to be able to see */var/tmp/test.txt* too).

To test/prove this, move the file to */var/tmp* on Server A and try again. Ta-da! You're welcome.....